# How do I check if an IEnumerable<T> starts with another IEnumerable<T> in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, ienumerable

I recently came across a scenario where I needed to check if an `IEnumerable<T>` began with some `IEnumerable<T>` prefix. I searched and didn't find an existing StackOverflow answer for this, so I decided to contribute my own solution in the form of an answer below.

Comment: Please don't use StackOverflow as your personal blog. Ask a question, but don't ask and answer a question in one hit like that.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't see what's wrong with answering my own question. This is a real problem I ran into, and others may run into as well. I'm sharing my knowledge with the rest of the world so other devs can Google this quickly and find a solution, instead of wasting time writing their own implementation.

Comment: I remembered seeing it somewhere that it was frowned upon, but I can't find that reference now. So happy days. Go for it.

Answer (score 7):

Your extension is fine but you can use the already existing `Enumerable.Zip` + `All`:

```
var longerSeq = new[] { "SOME", "IMPORTANT", "WORDS" };
var shorterSeq = new[] { "some", "important" };

bool startsWithCaseInsensitive = longerSeq 
    .Zip(shorterSeq, (l, s) =>  string.Equals(l, s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .All(b => b);   // are all bools true? Returns false on first false
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The method merges each element of the first sequence with an element
>   that has the same index in the second sequence. **If the sequences do
>   not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences
>   until it reaches the end of one of them**

Since `Zip` is using deferred execution it will not evaluate all if the first already yielded `false`.

Comment: This is not equivalent of the OP solution though. `StartsWith` should return `false` if the "prefix" sequence is longer than the "source" sequence. Which `Zip` implementation cannot distinguish.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a LINQ-style extension method that does the trick. I've made my implementation flexible by allowing you to pass in a custom equality comparer: for example, if you wanted `new[] { "SOME", "IMPORTANT", "WORDS" }.StartsWith(new[] { "some", "important" })` to be true, you could just add `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` after the `prefix` parameter.

```
public static bool StartsWith<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> prefix, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }
    if (prefix == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(prefix));
    }

    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    using (var sourceEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    using (var prefixEnumerator = prefix.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!sourceEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                return !prefixEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }

            if (!prefixEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (!comparer.Equals(sourceEnumerator.Current, prefixEnumerator.Current))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool result = longerList.Take(shorterList.Count).SequenceEqual(shorterList);
```

you can also add compare method to SequenceEqual :

```
 bool result = longerList.Take(shorterList.Count).SequenceEqual(shorterList, new MyComparer<string>);
```

See: [Enumerable.SequenceEqual Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx)